# Creating a high number from this grid using minimal mathematical operations

Tags: formation-of-numbers, puzzle-creation

I'm creating a puzzle (pictured below). From this grid, how could I output a 10-digit number? The tiles cannot be moved or changed.

[image: Puzzle grid of Scrabble-like tiles containing Braille icons and number values]

Instruction-wise, I would like to provide my players with some minimalist info about how to solve the puzzle, fitting onto a single Scrabble-size tile (see below). So far, the best I've come up with is having a double-sided Scrabble tile like this as a hint:

[image: Instructions tile version 1] or [image: Instructions tile version 2]

These give **63 x 11 = 693** and **28 x 28 = 784** (depending on whether you *count the number of spots* on tiles in all words placed in a particular direction - horizontal or vertical - or *sum their tile values*). Concatenating these together gives either **693784** or **784693**.

This is a good start, but unfortunately these are only 6-digit numbers and I would like to get a 9- or 10-digit number (to mimic a phone number).

Any creative ideas for how I could achieve this, given the setup as in the main image above?

**NOTE:** I would prefer to use basic mathematical operations only (+, -, * and /) to make sure young teens can play the game.

Comment: Can you explain where the 63x11 and 28x28 come from? The tiles in the image only have values of 1, 2 or 4. Are there some other rules that you have omitted? (I can easily create a 10-digit number just by putting ten of the tiles in a line.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking to design a puzzle is too open-ended for our format (see [Would puzzle-construction challenge questions be off-topic for this site?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5658/69582) and [Can we ask for puzzles?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6096/69582))

Comment: @bobble **From the tour**: "Puzzling Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those who **create**, solve, and study puzzles."

Comment: @fljx this is the sum of vertical lines and the sum horizontal lines, sometime using the domino's facing value or using the domino's point value

Comment: I think that this question is okay. It looks to me like the OP has already created a puzzle and just needs some help to 'fix' it so that a numeric message can be encoded within it. There won't necessarily be one 'correct' answer, but with SO and many other sites there are multiple ways to write useful code to help someone with a query, so I'd reason that it's fine to have a question on PSE where there are multiple ways to suggest a fix. (We do the same for broken Rubik's Cubes already!)

Comment: @Will I still don't understand what you are trying to explain. What is the "facing value"? I assume the "point value" is the number (like a scrabble tile), but the only other thing on each tile is a braille-like 2x3 grid of dots. I can't see any dominos. Please update the question to clarify how you are reaching your example number, and why that is the best that you have achieved. I still feel that there are some unstated restrictions that are stopping you easily reaching your target 9- or 10- digit number.

Comment: @fljx Will is referring to the total number of spots on the tiles and the sum of all tile values as two separate quantities. So 63 is the number of spots on all vertical words' tiles, 11 is the sum of tile values in the horizontal word; 28 is both the number of spots on the horizontal word's tiles *and* the sum of tile values in the vertical words. An additional thing to note is that all of the tiles when converted to Braille spell words in French: MES DOIGTS, MURS, VILLE, TOI and REGARDENT - linguistics may come into play during these exchanges in comments.

Comment: Wow I didn't recognize it was braille ! Thanks a lot @Stiv !

Comment: @will that line in the tour refers to the fact that people create their own puzzles *and then post them as questions*

Comment: @bobble No. "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about creating, solving, and studying puzzles." -> https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Will Please read the links I had in my first comment. We can answer questions such as "How do I design a Sudoku to use the X-wing strategy?", but questions such as "make me a puzzle that I like" are too broad. Those sentences you're quoting at me are summaries which must be interpreted in the context of how the community understands them. How do we know how the community understands them? Well, we could discuss on Meta Puzzling, which is what I linked to, and where there are archived discussions about how creating a puzzle is out-of-scope

Comment: @bobble personally, this question feels a lot less like "make me a puzzle that I like" than it does "can you give me some advice on how to continue with this puzzle that I'm working on", not too different from your stated example of designing a sudoku with a particular strategy in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that would use *zero* mathematical operations, bar basic addition...

It seems to me that the background to your photograph is just something that was lying around where you happened to assemble the tiles - but if the style of your puzzle allows it, **the playing surface can be just as useful as the tiles themselves**.

For example, you could construct a board that has particular regions indicated by coloured rectangles, with the expectation that the values of any tiles within those can be added up to form the digits for your phone number. For example, to make 555-1234567, and using a roughly rainbow-coloured ordering, you could design the game board to have something like this designed upon it:

[image: Gameboard with coloured rectangles]

Alternatively, you could use coloured markers around the edges to indicate that any values in similar-coloured rows or columns should be summed:

[image: Gameboard with coloured squares in the margins]

In fact, if using border markers you don't even need to use colours - you could use letters of the alphabet in order, or Greek alphabet characters even. Anything that might make a useful *ordered* key. This would also be a more friendly approach for players who may be colour-blind.

(Considering you are trying to provide players with minimal extraneous equipment, you could even just provide them with an accompanying 'key' image rather than a board itself. Or if using the second approach, you could give them two strips of paper, one for each axis, with the shapes/symbols on them; they would just need to align these strips with the grid.)

Don't forget that the playing tiles are not the only thing at your disposal here - the 'scenery' can be used!