# A Trivial Pursuit #07 (Geography 2/4): String Theory

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, geography, letters

<sub>This is part 7 of [A Trivial Pursuit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a60644%20is%3aq%20%22a%20trivial%20pursuit%22&searchOn=3), a 25-part puzzle hunt. Each part is solvable on its own, with the exception of the meta-puzzle at the end.</sub>

---

If

| e* |  |
| --- | --- |
| t* | u* |
| v* | w* |
| x* | y* |

is H...

**What relevant (if outdated) 4-letter word do the following tables spell?**

| *or* |  |
| --- | --- |
| *do* | *if* |
| *so* | *ti* |
| *in* | *no* |

| *sia* |  |
| --- | --- |
| *cara* | *tash* |
| *cat* | *orla* |
| *nina* | *tina* |

| *s*u*m* |  |
| --- | --- |
| *i*r*e* | *n*o*t* |
| *e*y*e* | *n*a*g* |
| *t*u*b* | *s*e*e* |

| *f* |  |
| --- | --- |
| *j* | *q* |
| *w* | *x* |
| *y* | *z* |

Comment: the three dots after H are deliberate I believe?

Comment: @CatProgrammer Purely punctuation choice. Didn't look right with just a comma. Nothing significant for the puzzle.

Comment: I get the feeling this has to do with how many countries have certain letter combinations.  The problem is, there is no definitive list of countries, which makes it hard to figure out.  (e.g.  Depending on which list you look at, Taiwan might be included or not.  Some lists use East Timor while others use Timor-Leste.  Is it officially Ivory Coast, or Côte D'Ivoire?  Swaziland or Eswatini?)  

If I am in fact on the right track, can you provide a link to the list you used, so that everyone is on the same page (literally and figuratively)?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain (Hmm, how to reply helpfully without giving spoilers?!) I shall suffice to say that this puzzle does not really rely on *counting* anything like that, as I am all too aware that official lists have variations from one to the next. I am pretty confident that what this puzzle *does* rely on should not be affected by something like what you describe though. Apologies for remaining somewhat cryptic in my response at this stage!

Comment: @Stiv No worries.  That response is helpful enough.

Comment: (PS Separately to the feedback above... Definitely eSwatini over Swaziland these days - officially renamed in 2018 - but the other two you named will continue to cause arguments in pub quizzes for years to come because those sources seemingly vary on preference...)

Comment: Western Sahara is another ambiguous one like Taiwan.  Some people recognize it as a separate country, while others support Morocco's claim to it.

Comment: How weird. I saw your puzzle and then created [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/122342/5373), without having any idea that yours also related to countries and cities. (Maybe I subconsciously saw your [tag:geography] tag and then forgot it.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Ha, it happens! Coincidentally, on the same day I also answered [a question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/122334/60644) which had a very prominent use of the secret mechanism here...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> **KIEV**, capital of Ukraine. The word is outdated, because nowadays one is supposed to use the Ukrainian transliteration Kyiv instead of the older one, which is associated with Russia and the Soviet era. The word is relevant, because this puzzle is about [capitals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_national_capitals).

Each of the tables ...

> ... describes a single letter. There are 2 by 3 table cells below the header in bold, which suggests [Braille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Braille).
>
>  The contents of the table are patterns, where an asterisk means: one or several letters go here. The header describes a **continent**, the regular cells describe a national **capital**. If there is a capital matching the pattern in that continent, place a dot in that cell, if there isn't, leave the cell blank.

The H example

> The **e*** is **E**urope and some of the patterns are matched by (e.g.) **T**irana (Albania), **V**ienna (Austria) and **W**arsaw (Poland), giving the letter **H** in Braille:
>
> ```
> e*
>
> t*      u*        o ·
> v*      w*        o o
> x*      y*        · ·
> ```

The first letter

> The matches in N**or**th America are (e.g.) San Salva**do**r (El Salvador) and Wash**in**gton, DC (U.S.A.), giving the letter **K**:
>
> ```
> *or*
>
> *do*      *if*        o ·
> *so*      *ti*        · ·
> *in*      *no*        o ·
> ```

The second letter

> The matches in A**sia** are **Tash**kent (Uzbekistan) and Mus**cat** (Oman). They produce an **I**.
>
> ```
> *sia*
>
> *cara*      *tash*        · o
> *cat*       *orla*        o ·
> *nina*      *tina*        · ·
> ```

The third letter

> **S**o**u**th A**m**erica is home to Buenos A**ire**s (Argentina) and Sa**n**ti**ag**o de Chile. They spell an **E**:
>
> ```
> *s*u*m*
>
> *i*r*e*     *n*o*t*         o ·
> *e*y*e*     *n*a*g*         · o
> *t*u*b*     *s*e*e*         · ·
> ```

The fourth letter

> The matches in A**f**rica are, among others, Abu**j**a (Nigeria), Freeto**w**n (Sierra Leone), Conakr**y** (Guinea) and Bra**z**zaville (Congo) for a **V**:
>
> ```
> *f*
>
> *j*         *q*         o ·
> *w*         *x*         o ·
> *y*         *z*         o o
> ```

Comment: This is right (well done!), and by the looks of it you didn't need to use the hidden acrostic clue either... Intended just as a pointer as to what each separate table represented...

Comment: Now that you mention it, I can see it, but I'm usually quite good at overlooking these artfully crafted extra hints. Instead, I usually work through a typical puzzler's bag of tricks in alphabetical order. I'm lucky that it was B and Cs this time round. `:)`

Comment: rot13(Ohwhzohen'f ab ybatre gur pncvgny, ohg fbzrguvat yvxr Nohwn fgvyy jbexf)

Comment: Good point, @Jafe, and thanks for the suggestion. I would probably have replaced it with  Adidjan  ...

Comment: @Stiv what is this hidden acrostic clue you are referring to?

Comment: @CatProgrammer: Look at the first letters of the first three tables (but not their headers in bold) after the example.