# Order the cities, then find which one is not described

Tags: visual, geography, letters

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #14: Think inside the (very small) box!](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/monthly-topic-challenge-14-think-inside-the-very-small-box).</sub>

[image: GIZA, OSLO, ANKARA, ELBASAN]

Here are four cities, each of them in a different country. What you need to do is the following.

- Figure out the **order** of the cities, and put them into the grid in the right order.
- Remember where you are and extract a **code** from each city, replacing it by its code in the grid.
- From the codes, find a **description** and figure out which city does *not* match the description.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, I looked at Elbasan, which I wasn't aware of previously, and noticed that

> It is the fourth most populated city in Albania.

From that I found that

> Oslo is the most populated, Ankara the second most populated, Giza the third most populated and Elbasan the fourth most populated city of their respective countries, which are Norway, Turkey, Egypt and Albania respectively.

I placed the cities in the grid as follows

> `OSLO    ANKARA`
>
> `GIZA    ELBASAN`
>
>  This is just writing them in that order from top to bottom, left to right, like one would with English text.

I then replaced the cities with

> Their countries two letter ISO code
>
>  `NO  TR`
>
>  `EG  AL`

This left me with

> The phrase "*not regal*", i.e. not relating to a king or queen. Of the four cities only **Oslo** is currently the seat of a monarch. Therefore, it is the outlier and the answer to the puzzle.